# How to make confidential Library Modules

Tags: android, encryption, lib

I am Creating AAR File for deploy to client , and I don't want to anyone to read data of that file , by using Pro_Guard Rules. I can encrypt data but after encryption even I can't use that Library because all File name and Variable are changed. So how can I encrypted Library that can perform it's task.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude your public apis from Proguard, so they don't get obfuscated. Just obfuscate your internal library stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Proguard does not encrypt nor is used for encryption. What Proguard does is obfuscation.

To obfuscate your library, you need to enable proguard for it: `minifyEnabled true` in its build.gradle file.